# How to stack a portable countertop / tabletop Dishwasher on top of a front load washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine, installation, dishwasher, placement

I have limited space because all the cabinets were already setup long back. A Bosch front load washing machine (60cm (d) x 60cm (b) x 85 cm (h) is placed in this space. There is a gap of 60.5 cm from the top of the washing machine free as of now.

Can a portable countertop / tabletop dishwasher (http://levant.beko.com/dishwashers/dtc36810w/) of dimensions 59.5cm (h) x 55cm (b) x 50cm(d) be stacked on top of the front load washing machine?
What's the best way to go about it and any precautionary measures needed?

Updated/Edited:

The dishwasher is not a Full size one but a table top dishwasher designed to be placed on countertops. Example below.

[image: Typical installation of this dishwasher in a kitchen]

As there is limited clearance and only 1 cm gap left considering both the appliances height, am planning to place a plywood top of 10 mm thickness and size 60 mm by 60 mm on top of the washing machine with an anti slip map. 
Is this a feasible option or some other material will work?
Will the washing machine be able to take the weight and handle any vibrations the countertop dishwasher may have?

Image of what i am planning:
[image: Plan]

Comment: I'd be concerned about whether the Bosch can handle the weight and vibration of a dishwasher. If you can build a frame around it and a plywood (or even "real" counter) on top, that would be best, so the dishwasher weight & vibration would go the frame down to the floor instead of into the washing machine.

Comment: Have added an image of my plan. Weight of the tabletop dishwasher is around 15 kg (a single person can easily lift it on his own based on reviews) Inputs will help.

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely be done, although the way I did it was to create a countertop over the washing machine, boxing in the washing machine, (*the same as any countertop you would normally sit the tabletop dishwasher*) thereby making them separate entities.

All that needed to be done was to drill a fair sized hole for the pipes and cables to fit through the countertop behind the dishwasher, not visible, and the dishwasher can come forward to be flush with the countertop. It is never going to topple over, why would it, it's only the door that will venture out  and that won't topple it. (*I have a Bosch countertop dishwasher, and it has never ever unbalanced*) I'm even considering boxing in the dishwasher so that the microwave can sit on top. (*I don't have any cabinets above, to get in the way.*) and I can reach it quite easily, like an eye level oven.

The only thing that may be a safety issue is if all appliances are sharing one outlet. I would make sure they each had their own  so as not to overload it. Overall, it has worked for me and it's all next to the kitchen sink so the plumbing is all in one place, nice and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why it could not be done.  Of course you'll need to solve the problem of how to keep the DW in place on top of the washer.  Most DW feet that I have seen are expecting to sit on the floor and they may not hit a good spot on top of the washer.

One thing that comes to mind is cutting a sheet of plywood that you can mount on top of the washer that has indents bored in the locations for the DW feet to sit it.

Note also that you'll need to secure the DW so that it doesn't fall over toward you.  Usually they are unbalanced when the door is open and the mounting under the counter top is what keep them in place. You'll need to hold it down from the back or the bottom somehow, perhaps with some straps.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a terrible idea.

So to do this you will need to...

- build a very solid shelf to sit the dishwasher on.
- you probably need to buy a regular (not portable dishwasher).   The portable ones are a lot heavier so they don't tip.   You don't need that weight up there.
- you will actually need to build a box for the dishwasher.   You need a top to keep it from tipping.   You need brackets to keep it from inching forward.
- The plumbing will be a little tricky with dishwasher on top as you want the disposal line going up a bit before going down.

Even if done properly and building a super enclosed shelf, you have a huge injury risk waiting to happen.   Shorter people and kids trying to get stuff out of the top - note that they door has to be open to roll out the racks... They fall or whatever onto the door, does the shelf/box support it?   How is this super heavy dishwasher (dishes + water + its weight) effect the shelf over time.   How does the washing machine which induces movement effect this shelf/box?   Can this be done?  Sure anything can be done.   But this sounds like the beginning of a Darwin award story.

If you have limited cabinet space but have the ability to stack these then why not just take a cabinet out that is next to the washer and put it on top of the washer.   This would probably be much more functional and more convenient.

Comment: This is an actual **table top** dishwasher. It is designed to be installed on top of a counter, under a counter or in a cabinet. Based on the instruction manual, it is designed to be permanently installed but does not need to be mounted as securely as a typical (USA full size) dishwasher.

Comment: A **shelf**, +1. That's what we put in our RV; a shelf for a dishwasher, in the already too-short shower that we only hosed-off kids in anyway.

Comment: Yes it's a table top dishwasher.  I want to avoid having to take out the cabinet if it is possible.

Comment: We have a Bosch table-top dishwasher (above our washing machine, as it happens). There is absolutely no need for it to be secured to the wall in order to stop it tipping.